# Get location address from Latitude and Longitude in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want after click on google map and getting Latitude and Longitude get location place from they and put it (address) in filed `input#searchTextField`. What do i do?

I tried as, but don't work for me:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DXkZJ/

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" style="text-align:    left;width:357px;direction: ltr;">
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 350px;width: 500px;margin: 0.6em;"></div>



 $(function () {
     var lat = 44.88623409320778,
         lng = -87.86480712897173,
         latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

     //zoomControl: true,
     //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

     var mapOptions = {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
         zoom: 13,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         panControl: true,
         panControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
         },
         zoomControl: true,
         zoomControlOptions: {
             style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
         }
     },
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
         marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             icon: image
         });

     var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
         types: ["geocode"]
     });

     autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
     var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

     google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
         infowindow.close();
         var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
         if (place.geometry.viewport) {
             map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
         } else {
             map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
             map.setZoom(17);
         }

         moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
         alert(place.name);
         $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
         $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
     });
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
         $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
         $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
         alert(event.latLng.place.name)
     });
     $("#searchTextField").focusin(function () {
         $(document).keypress(function (e) {
             if (e.which == 13) {
                 return false;
                 infowindow.close();
                 var firstResult = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();
                 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                 geocoder.geocode({
                     "address": firstResult
                 }, function (results, status) {
                     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                         var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                             lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                             placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                             latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                         moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                         $("input").val(firstResult);
                         alert(firstResult)
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     });

     function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
         marker.setIcon(image);
         marker.setPosition(latlng);
         infowindow.setContent(placeName);
         //infowindow.open(map, marker);
     }
 });​
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so firstly you need reverse geocoding, not regular geocoding, because you are going from a latitude/longitude into an address rather than the other way around (see [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding)). Secondly your key listener would never do anything because it almost immediately states `return false`; in this case you probably want `event.stopPropogation()`. Furthermore google maps will intercept your mouse clicks at a greater depth in the DOM tree than `document`, so the event will never be listened that highly anyway.

So what I did was to change your geocode into a reverse geocode, as well as move the code in the document listener into the google listener. If you wanted to retain the behaviour of the listener being added on focus, you can simply create a new listener on the map object. Here is a [working jsfiddle demonstrating these changes](http://jsfiddle.net/DXkZJ/1/), hopefully this helps.

Comment: its really great, But google map doesn't shows location of user, **How do i track location of user???**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the gmap developers api. 
for topic [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) .
You will got your answer.

Comment: @jennifer Jolie : why negative I just give what i know!

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code after moveMarker() function

```
$("#map_canvas").click(function() {          
    $("#searchTextField").val($(".MapLat").val() +", "+$(".MapLon").val());
});
```

Hope, this is what you needed :)