# How do I get address by given lat/long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

How do I get address by given lat/long  not location? I have tried with
"Reverse Geocoding" but it's showing only the location name.

My code is this:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var marker2;

function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    //alert(event.latLng);      
    geocoder.geocode({
        'latLng': event.latLng
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status ==
            google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
                alert(results[1].formatted_address);
            } else {
                alert('No results found');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
}); <!--click event--> }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Hint: http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=en

Comment: Why are you using the 2nd result (results[1])?  Perhaps the first result (results[0]) might be what you are looking for...

Comment: Thank you, you are right, results[0] giving the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address with street number is at index 0. Use

```
results[0].formatted_address
```

instead of

```
results[1].formatted_address
```

And you will get the address

For example, at index 0 you get: *"36 Osborne Street, Wollongong ..."*, at index 1 you get *"Wollongong Hospital Crown St, Wollongong ..."*.

You can get components of `formatted_address` using

```
results[0].address_components[0]
...
results[0].address_components[5]
```

Comment: Hi Anto,  I want a info box instead of alert  but problem is, when clicking any point it showing the content but when click new location the previous one not removed.                           var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: event.latLng,
     map: map,
     draggable: true
    });
    infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker3);

Comment: What do you want to achieve: when you click on some location that marker is created and infowindow opened? And when you click on another location that merker is moved to that location and infowindow updated with new address?

Answer (score 3):

Check these two references:

[How to get address location from latitude and longitude in Google Map.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511597/how-to-get-address-location-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-map)

[Get location address from Latitude and Longitude in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051106/get-location-address-from-latitude-and-longitude-in-google-maps)

The answer of these will help you.

use this URL to get the address:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true
```

Comment: I visited this post, but not understand how do i get this pragmatically.can you help me

Comment: @user1987095 you can use the ajax of jquery simply to get the address.

Comment: Thanks for your help,"Get location address from Latitude and Longitude in google maps" help me

Comment: @user1987095 my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
results[1].geometry.location
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass your lat and long to the following query string, and you will get a json array, fetch your city from there

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838&sensor=true`

NOTE: you have to pass your api key into queryParams, that you can generate from google Clouds

Answer (score 1):

Pass your latitude, longitude, and API key to the following API

```js
$.get({ url: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${lat},${longi}&sensor=false&key=${apikey}`, success(data) {
    console.log(data.results[0].formatted_address);
}});
```