# How to get the address from Google's Api coordinates JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created a map on my website. User can add multiple markers. And on the other page I created a call to these markers. 
Here is a string:

> string
>   '[{"lat":"40.7181193798","lng":"-84.4847297668","label":"A"},{"lat":"40.9530752681","lng":"-83.9779055864","label":"A"}]'

How to make it display only the address. Like "USA,NY,gikalo street ..."
And created a link to Google maps with this location.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743351/how-do-i-get-address-by-given-lat-long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var z='[{"lat":"40.7181193798","lng":"-84.4847297668","label":"A"},{"lat":"40.9530752681","lng":"-83.9779055864","label":"A"}]'

var JSONArray=JSON.parse(z);
var lat=JSONArray[0].lat;//For first obj
var long=JSONArray[0].long;//For first obj

var dataURL="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&sensor=true";
```

You can fetch your data by using this url Just you need to parse your JSON in response you wil get appropriate result.

Comment: Ty, may be u now how to create link to GM?

Comment: refer this http://www.expertphp.in/article/show-marker-on-google-map-using-latitude-and-longitude-with-info-window

Comment: may be u now, can I add 2 location in one request?

Comment: basically location is depend on location code. you can't add it one request. you can make two different request. and merget it in one request

Comment: The Google Maps docs have been updated and as of June 2014 and the &sensor parameter is no longer required for JavaScript or Web Service API calls. See docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You will need API key inorder to make the Google Map API request everytime.